# Convert from int to binary or hex in mikroc

Tags: type-conversion, microcontroller, pic, mikroc

I got an int value from 0 to 255 and I want to convert that value to hex or binary so i can use it into an 8 bit register(PIC18F uC).
How can i do this conversion?
I tried to use IntToHex function from Conversion Library but the output of this function is a char value, and from here i got stuck.
I'm using mikroc for pic.
Where should I start?
Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, bits is bits.  Show us a specific example of what you want to do programmatically.  I have this value in this base that I obtain in this way and want it converted to this value in this base in this form so I can use it here...

Comment: A number from 0 to 255 can fit in an 8-bit register, that's the only thing you have to worry about. Learn numerical limits of 8 or 16-bit signed/unsigned integers. Hexadecimal, octal, decimal or binary - these are just *representations* of that same integer. The value that you have is (usually) encoded in the microcontroller as a *binary* number, and that should only concern you when you want to do bitwise operations (extract, mask or shift individual bits). The only place where you would want to change the *representation* into a hex/oct/dec would be when displaying the value to the user.

Comment: In other words, `IntToHex` probably returns a `char` **pointer**, i.e. a string of characters, because it's converting an integer to a textual representation for display. For example, if your value is `255`, `IntToHex` will probably return a null-terminated string `"FF"`. But to assign the value to the register, just assign the **actual value**, not the array of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem. Many don't understand that, Decimal 15 is same as Hex F is same as Octal 17 is same as Binary 1111.

Different number systems are for Humans, for CPU, it's all Binary!

When OP says,

> I got an int value from 0 to 255 and I want to convert that value to
>   hex or binary so i can use it into an 8 bit register(PIC18F uC).

It reflects this misunderstanding. Probably, because debugger is configured to show "decimal" values and sample code/datasheet shows Hex value for register operations.

So, when you get "int" value from 0 to 255, you can directly write that number to 8-bit register. You don't have to convert it to hex. Hex is just representation which makes Human's life easy.

What you can do is - this is good practise --

```
REG_VALUE = (unsigned char) int_value;
```